# Presto SQL save query results in variable

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a database that I am querying with athena.

I am using subqueries to select a subset of the data like so

```
(select item , max(date) from (select * from tablename where x=y) 
groupby 1 ) as p
LEFT JOIN
(select item ,date , max(date2) from (select * from tablename where x=y) 
groupby 1,2 ) as q
ON p.item=q.item ;
```

can I save the query results of

```
select * from tablename where x=y
```

in a variable `VAR` so that we need not query it again and again and also to make query look cleaner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such concept as variable in Presto. You can using the query results from S3 as the source for the new table but I would argue that it can be brittle and cumbersome. As for "reusing" the code - you can achieve that with [`WITH` clause](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#with-clause) designed especially for that:

```
with cte as (select * from tablename where x=y),
p as (
    select item, max(date)
    from cte
    group by 1
), 
q as(
    select item, date, max(date2)
    from cte
    group by 1,2
)

select *
from p
LEFT JOIN q as q ON p.item = q.item;
```

Another approach which can be worth looking at is using grouping sets (see corresponding point of "Complex Grouping Operations" in the [`GROUP BY` Clause docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#group-by-clause)):

```sql
with dataset(item, date, date2) as (
    VALUES ('id1', 1, 1),
    ('id1', 1, 2),
    ('id1', 2, 1),
    ('id2', 1, 1)
)

select item, date, max(date) max_date, max(date2) max_date2
from dataset
where true -- x=y
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (item),
    (item, date))
order by item, date
```

Output

| item | date | max_date | max_date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| id1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| id1 |  | 2 | 2 |
| id2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| id2 |  | 1 | 1 |

`date` will be equal to `max_date` for rows which are grouped both by `item` and `date`